# How to "css3 blink effect" with visibility property

Tags: css, visibility, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to get an old blink effect on some DIVs. The should start FROM invisible and then turn visible for a while, then over and over in an infinite blink.
CSS specs says Visible is animatable as Visible (I understood this as there can not be transition ie fade in and out, just blink. That's what I want).

However, my code doesn't work. DIVS remain visible all time, no flicker, no blink..

Any hint on why is this happening?

```
<style type="text/css">
.shape{
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(217, 215, 30, 0.5);
    visibility:visible;    
}
.star-anim1 {   
    animation-name:blink;
    animation-direction:normal;
    animation-delay:5sg;
    animation-duration:5s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
.star1{
    top:80px;
    left:60px;
}
.star2{
    right:30px;
    top:60px;
}

@keyframes blink{   

   from{
        visibility:hidden;
   }
   to{
        visibility:visible;

    }
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="position:relative;">

<div class="star-anim1 shape star1"></div>
<div class="star-anim1 shape star2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need vendor prefixes for keyframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to use animation, it's important to know your [vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for this effect.

---

[the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

---

```css
div{
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
}


@keyframes blink {
 0% {display: blue}
 50% {background-color: transparent;color:transparent;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
 0% {background-color: blue}
 50% {background-color: transparent;color:transparent;}
}
```

```html
<div>hello!!!!!!</div>
```

---

Your CSS animation specifies a first transition from 0% to 50% turning from hidden to visible which shows the element according to the rule above and then you specify a transition from 50% to 100% from visible to hidden, which also shows the element while playing. So the element it permanently visible.

By specifying

```
@keyframes toggle {
         from {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     50% {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     to {
            visibility:visible;
      }
 }
```

the element will stay hidden until 50% and then abruptly appear. To hide it at the end, you need to add visibility:hidden to the main style sheet rule not to the keyframes.

```css
.blink_me {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-name: toggle;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: toggle;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: toggle;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes toggle {
         from {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     50% {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     to {
            visibility:visible;
      }
 }
@-webkit-keyframes toggle {
         from {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     50% {
            visibility:hidden;
         }
     to {
            visibility:visible;
      }
 }
```

```html
<div class="blink_me">everyday i'm toggling!</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the thing of using visibility, and NOT opacity is that I need a real BLINK (no transitions--> fade in/out within miliseconds). I'm aware of vendor prefixes. To simplify I'm using the standars and testing in Chrome and Firefox, lasts versions (so I know for sure works the standard declarations)

Comment: Maybe I explained myself badly. I'm not trying to alternate between 2 background colors. What I want is to alterante the visibility of a given DOM object (say a div, an spam or whatever) using keyframes an the visibility property. So, none of the given examples are valid.

Comment: @user2500929: try that last sample now. Should be what you're looking for!

Comment: Am I right If I say the animation wasn't working because interpolating 'visible' property is done in a way that 0 and 1 point of the timing function consider both points Visible according to the following Mozilla doc?:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#Interpolation

Comment: @user2500929: I believe so.